# What is the trivia tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, policy

Recently I posted a trivia question using the [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tag, however, it has now been closed as OT with this [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66098/is-it-the-crown-that-makes-the-king-or-is-it-his-throne#comment199812_66098) "I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle; it is simply a trivia question.." after it was learned that it was *actually* a trivia question as the tag indicates.

The question is current, difficult to guess and, researchable. A bit of fun.

So, my question is, what is the purpose of the trivia tag if it is not for trivia questions?

Answer (score 4):

The [tag wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/trivia/info) for the [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tag states (emphasis mine):

> Trivia puzzles are puzzles that are based on uncommon but usually notable knowledge about a certain subject. These puzzles will tend to deal with a lot of physical and historical facts, rather than the logic behind a certain mathematical construct, and are more prosaic than riddles.
>
> Questions in this category may require research to answer. Generally the information should be Googlable, or at least publicly available.
>
> ***Puzzles that are just trivia questions are off-topic on this Stack Exchange, but puzzles that involve some form of reasoning around the trivia are generally welcome.***

The tag is meant to be used for **puzzles** or **questions about puzzles** that *involve* trivia.  Trivia questions themselves have nothing to do with **the creation and solving of puzzles** and thus are off-topic for this site.

Click the tag to see a list of valid questions that use the [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tag.

Comment: Alright, I have to accept. I did read the tag wiki before posting and, I thought that the framing of the question and use of misdirection covered the requirement for "some form of reasoning around the trivia" but, clearly that is insufficient.

Comment: To be fair, that wording isn't ideal. I'd rather say "some form of *puzzle*" than "some form of *reasoning*". Having to reason does not a puzzle make.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Good thing it's a tag *wiki*.  It can be edited.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not really sure about my wording either. "puzzles that involve some form of puzzle" ... nope. It's often difficult to write good tag wikis on this site, so I'm fishing for input from others :-)